# Hibernate - Excepción MySQLSyntaxErrorException sobre un campo calculado (@Formula)

Tags: java, hibernate

Tengo dos campos calculados en mi entidad EnergiaActividadMedida en los que me valgo de la anotación `@Formula` que proporciona Hibernate.

A continuación muestro el fragmento de codigo que contiene las propiedades `@Formula`:

```
public class EnergiaActividadMedida implements Serializable {
    //...
    @Formula( "("
            + "select ifnull(sum("
            + "case "
            + "when v.unidadprincipal_fk = datos.unidadproduccion_fk then v.cantidadPrincipal "
            + "when v.unidadsecundaria_fk = datos.unidadproduccion_fk then v.cantidadSecundaria "
            + "else 0 end"
            + "), 0) "
            + "from "
            + "(select m.*, mc.centro_fk "
            + "from energiaactividadmedida m "
            + "inner join energiaactividadmedidacentro mc on mc.medida_fk = m.id) datos "
            + "left join venergiaactividadmedidacentrocantidadobjetivoaux v on v.energiaactividad_fk = datos.actividad_fk and v.centro_fk = datos.centro_fk and v.fecha BETWEEN datos.fechainicio and datos.fechafin "
            + "where datos.id = id"
            + ")" )
    private double cantidadProduccionCentros;
    @Formula( "("
            + "select ifnull("
            + "(case "
            + "when datos.objetivocentroproducto then sum(v.objetivo) / sum(v.cantidadPrincipal) "
            + "else datos.valorObjetivo end), 0) "
            + "from "
            + "(select m.*, mc.centro_fk, ea.objetivocentroproducto "
            + "from energiaactividadmedida m "
            + "inner join energiaactividad ea on m.actividad_fk = ea.id "
            + "inner join energiaactividadmedidacentro mc on mc.medida_fk = m.id) datos "
            + "left join venergiaactividadmedidacentrocantidadobjetivoaux v on v.energiaactividad_fk = datos.actividad_fk and v.centro_fk = datos.centro_fk and v.fecha BETWEEN datos.fechainicio and datos.fechafin "
            + "where datos.id = id"
            + ")" )
    private double valorObjetivo;

   //...
}
```

Hibernate transforma ambas fórmulas en el siguiente bloque SQL:

```
select
        energiaact0_.id as id76_,
        energiaact0_.actividad_fk as actividad9_76_,
        energiaact0_.created as created76_,
        energiaact0_.fechaFin as fechaFin76_,
        energiaact0_.fechaInicio as fechaIni4_76_,
        energiaact0_.fechaJornada as fechaJor5_76_,
        energiaact0_.turno_fk as turno10_76_,
        energiaact0_.unidadproduccion_fk as unidadp11_76_,
        energiaact0_.updated as updated76_,
        energiaact0_.valorexpresiondestino as valorexp7_76_,
        energiaact0_.valorexpresionorigen as valorexp8_76_,
        (select
            ifnull(sum(case 
                when v.unidadprincipal_fk = datos.unidadproduccion_fk then v.cantidadPrincipal 
                when v.unidadsecundaria_fk = datos.unidadproduccion_fk then v.cantidadSecundaria 
                else 0 
            end),
            0) 
        from
            (select
                m.*,
                mc.centro_fk 
            from
                energiaactividadmedida m 
            inner join
                energiaactividadmedidacentro mc 
                    on mc.medida_fk = m.id) energiaact0_.datos 
        left join
            venergiaactividadmedidacentrocantidadobjetivoaux v 
                on v.energiaactividad_fk = datos.actividad_fk 
                and v.centro_fk = datos.centro_fk 
                and v.fecha BETWEEN datos.fechainicio and datos.fechafin 
        where
            datos.id = energiaact0_.id
        ) as formula0_, (
            select
                ifnull((case 
                    when datos.objetivocentroproducto then sum(v.objetivo) / sum(v.cantidadPrincipal) 
                    else datos.valorObjetivo 
                end),
                0) 
            from
                (select
                    m.*,
                    mc.centro_fk,
                    ea.objetivocentroproducto 
                from
                    energiaactividadmedida m 
                inner join
                    energiaactividad ea 
                        on m.actividad_fk = ea.idinner 
                join
                    energiaactividadmedidacentro mc 
                        on mc.medida_fk = m.id) energiaact0_.datos 
            left join
                venergiaactividadmedidacentrocantidadobjetivoaux v 
                    on v.energiaactividad_fk = datos.actividad_fk 
                    and v.centro_fk = datos.centro_fk 
                    and v.fecha BETWEEN datos.fechainicio and datos.fechafin 
            where
                datos.id = energiaact0_.id
            ) as formula1_ 
        from
            energiaactividadmedida energiaact0_ 
        where
            energiaact0_.actividad_fk=? 
            and energiaact0_.fechaInicio<? 
            and energiaact0_.fechaFin>? 
        order by
            energiaact0_.fechaInicio,
            energiaact0_.id
```

El problema es que al establecer un alias a la subquery, Hibernate introduce un punto (`energiaact0_.datos`), con lo cual Mysql lanza la siguiente excepción:

> Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '.datos left join
>   venergiaactividadmedidacentrocantidadobjetivoaux v on v.energia' at
>   line 1

¿Cómo puedo modificar la consulta de estos campos calculados para que genere una query correcta?

Comment: No sé si lo resuelve, pero ¿probaste con `AS`? ... En tu caso: `... from (select ...) AS datos left join ...`

Answer (score 1):

Revisa los espacios para que tu Query sea correcto, por ejemplo tienes este error:

```
 + "inner join energiaactividad ea on m.actividad_fk = ea.id"
            + "inner join energiaactividadmedidacentro mc on mc.medida_fk = m.id) datos "
```

Debe existir un espacio para concatenar "inner join ...."

```
 + "inner join energiaactividad ea on m.actividad_fk = ea.id " //agregar espacio!
            + "inner join energiaactividadmedidacentro mc on mc.medida_fk = m.id) datos "
```

te recomiendo como buena practica, agregar espacio al final de cada linea.

Comment: He revisado y corregido la query de @Formula, sin embargo sigue dando el mismo error.